# Fixing a out of bound error while doubling all the letters except the first and the last letters

Tags: java

This code should double all but the first and last letter in message. Fix the code so that it doesn’t cause an out of bounds error.
I can't figure out where i am going wrong.

```
public class Loop2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String result = "";
  String message = "watch out";
  int pos = 0;
 while (pos < message.length())
   {
      result = result + message.substring(pos,pos+2);
      pos = pos + 1;
   }
   System.out.println(result);
```

}
}

Comment: When `pos` is `message.length() - 1`, what do you expect `message.substring(pos, pos + 2)` to return?

Comment: Change the condition to `pos < message.length() - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your condition is :

```
pos < message.length()
```

So when you do :

```
message.substring(pos,pos+2);
```

It will throw an out of bound exception beacause pos will be 1 + message.length().

A solution is to change your condition to

```
pos < message.length() - 1
```

Or is to use the `charAt()` function. `charAt(i)` return the character in a String at the index `i`